# Mongodb does not fetch the embedded document with php

Tags: php, mongodb

Here is the code it does not featch the embedded documents.

```
<?php 
   include 'vendor/dbcon.php';
       $documentlist = $state -> find(['s_name' => 'West Bengal'],
            ['projection' =>  ['_id' => 0, 'places._id' => 1]] );

    foreach ($documentlist as $doc) {
     echo $doc["places._id"] . "\n";
   }
 ?>
```

> ERROR shows:   Notice: Undefined index: places._id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Education\Home.php on line 130

if the code is like:

```
foreach ($documentlist as $doc) {
         echo $doc["_id"] . "\n";
       }
```

> then ERROR::   Notice: Undefined index: _id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Education\Home.php on line 130

database structure: Mongodb

```
 db.state.find().pretty()

{
        "_id" : "state1",
        "s_name" : "West Bengal",
        "places" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "Bardhaman",
                        "pin" : "754216"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "Jalpaiguri",
                        "pin" : "754217"
                }
        ]
}
```

please help me how can i print all places._id list(ex. Bardhaman, Jalpaiguri )

Comment: You didn't include `_id`. See? `'_id' => 0`

Comment: My bad. "places" is an array of course. You need to iterate on that from within the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the projection, it's just the notation to access is PHP notation and not "Dot notation" when in PHP. And of course "places" is an array, so you need to iterate:

```
  $documentlist = $state->find([],[ '_id' => 0, 'places._id' => 1 ]);

  foreach ($documentlist as $doc) {
    foreach($doc['places'] as $place) {
      echo $place['_id'] . "\n";
    }
  }
```

Produces:

```
Bardhaman
Jalpaiguri
```